# Is there any other sources of hydrogen carriers for the Electron Transport Chain other than the 3 main metabolic pathways?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, metabolism, energy-metabolism

I am learning about the 4 main metabolic pathways for cellular respiration. I learned that NADH and FADH2 hydrogen carriers are essential in the Electron Transport Chain, because they deposit their hydrogens (which consist of protons and electrons), which are used to power ATP synthase (reattaches ADP and Pi together to form ATP) in the inner mitochondrial membrane. The reduced hydrogen carriers must come from glycolysis, pyruvate oxidation, and the Krebs cycle. I'm wondering if all those pathways were inhibited (and essentially broken completely) let's say, is there any possible way for the Electron Transport Chain to get hydrogen so that it can still work?

Comment: Hey welcome to the site!  Just to clarify the start of the question slightly... We generally speak of the electron carriers carrying electrons, not hydrogens... it avoids confusion with the hydrogens which are being pumped across the mitochondrial membrane, which are **not** the hydrogens attached to NADH, for instance.  In fact, the energy from the electrons on NADH pumps 10 H+ across the membrane (and it only loses one in the process).  Also, NADH actually drops off four electrons, two of which are not associated with a hydrogen at all but rather the pyrimidine rings.

Comment: Yes, but you should wait until you meet them in your studies. And you seem to be looking at things backwards. It's not a question of getting the ETC to "work", it's a question of whether there are any oxidative pathways that produce NADH or FADH2 to provide energy for an organism through using the ETC. You're very welcome to this site, but finish reading the Tour (you'll get a badge so that we know you have), and look at the Help on asking questions.